# Command ["Wkhtmltopdf"] returned non-zero exit 6

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When trying to load a pdf using wkhtml to pdf i get this error

```
CalledProcessError at /Reservations/mybookings/1/pdf
Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--encoding', u'utf8', '--quiet', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdfc3a0GU.html', '-']' returned non-zero exit status -6
```

It was working on local but then when I deployed it to server and changed static directory it stopped working.

**Local settings**

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
STATIC_ROOT = 'static_cdn'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Production**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Edit Q to add static settings of local and prod! So that we can compare and suggest some solution

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying . I have updated above.

Comment: In prod, webserver will be serving your static files.

Comment: static files are showing such as images , only this pdf gives error.

Comment: Found a solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but i got same exit code -6. Checking apache logs i noticed that wkhtmltopdf can't connect to display (because on server usually there is no display).

So to fix it firstly install `xvfb` package on your server (via `sudo apt install xvfb` or whatever package manager you use). And then change value of the `WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD` in your `settings.py` from whatever you have to:

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = 'xvfb-run -a wkhtmltopdf'
```